# MAC OS - Create a simple script that runs terminal commands

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I have some terminal commands that need to be applied to some files.

I want the script to be applied to a file system of a parent folder, and within that folder a child project folder

here is the list of commands and the process that it needs to be done.

---

```bash
cd /Directory to Parent Folder.

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine 'Parent Folder Name'

xattr -d com.apple.macl 'Parent Folder Name'

cd '*Child Folder*'

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine '*ChildFolder*'/Assets/Wwise/API/Runtime/Plugins/Mac/Debug/AkSoundEngine.bundle

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine '*ChildFolder*'/Assets/Wwise/API/Runtime/Plugins/Mac/Release/AkSoundEngine.bundle

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine '*ChildFolder*'/Assets/Wwise/API/Runtime/Plugins/Mac/Profile/AkSoundEngine.bundle

chmod -R 777 'Parent Folder'
```

---

I would like the script to be in the same directory as the parent folder, and when you run it. it will do all the above commands

I may be asking this question completely in the wrong way but I want to know how to do this.

Is there a simple way to do this.

Thanks Again.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, you can use those `cd`'s in a script to navigate to the other dir.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html

Comment: Do you want to apply commands to all childfolders?

Comment: What you have *is* a shell script, which is nothing more than a text file containing shell commands. Is there a specific problem you are having with what you are trying to do?